# How to find the row number of a value in filtered sheet in only visible cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I used following syntax, but its not working. Please any one help on this.

```
minrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(mindat, Sheets("Inventory").Range("G2:G1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim SearchRange as Range
Set SearchRange = Sheets("Inventory").Range("G2:G1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not SearchRange is Nothing Then

    Dim FoundCell as Range
    Set FoundCell = SearchRange.Find(mindat, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not FoundCell is Nothing Then 
        minrow = FoundCell.Row
    End If

End If
```

Comment: Superb dude.. it worked